# htaccess : How to change htaccess in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

`http://www.bi-kay.com/demo/JEDWebsite/listing-projects/?type=ville`

to

`http://www.bi-kay.com/demo/JEDWebsite/listing-projects/ville/`

I write code

```
RewriteRule ^listing-projects/ville/(.*)$ listing-projects/?type=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?page_id=$1&type=$2 [L]
```

Comment: I follow this code but error not fount

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewriterule ^demo/JEDWebsite/listing-projects/?type=ville(.*)$ http://www.bi-kay.com/demo/JEDWebsite/listing-projects/ville/$1 [r=301,nc]
```